# How to separate rows by comma outside brackets in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

How can I separate rows by comma outside brackets in R?

I know that `disasters <- disasters %>% separate_rows(Location, sep = ",")` can be used to separate rows by comma, but how to make a condition on "out of the brackets only"?

I have a data table (disasters) that looks like:

```
<!-- +------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+--+ -->
<!-- | Start.date |  End.date  |         Country          |                                                          Region                                                          |  |  | -->
<!-- +------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+--+ -->
<!-- | 2005-10-01 | 2005-10-16 | Costa Rica               | Quepos (Aguirre district, Puntarenas province), Guanacaste province                                                      |  |  | -->
<!-- | 2016-11-23 | 2016-11-25 | Costa Rica               | Upala, Bagaces                                                                                                           |  |  | -->
<!-- | ...        | ...        | ...                      | ...                                                                                                                      |  |  | -->
<!-- | 2007-12-11 | 2007-12-17 | Dominican Republic (the) | Bonao city (Monsenor Nouel district, Monsenor Nouel province), Nagua district (Maria Trinidad Sanches province), Arenoso |  |  | -->
<!-- | ...        | ...        | ...                      | ...                                                                                                                      |  |  | -->
<!-- +------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+--+ -->
```

It should be transformed to be like:

```
<!-- +------------+------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--+--+ -->
<!-- | Start.date |  End.date  |         Country          |                            Region                             |  |  | -->
<!-- +------------+------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--+--+ -->
<!-- | 2005-10-01 | 2005-10-16 | Costa Rica               | Quepos (Aguirre district, Puntarenas province)                |  |  | -->
<!-- | 2005-10-01 | 2005-10-16 | Costa Rica               | Guanacaste province                                           |  |  | -->
<!-- | 2016-11-23 | 2016-11-25 | Costa Rica               | Upala                                                         |  |  | -->
<!-- | 2016-11-23 | 2016-11-25 | Costa Rica               | Bagaces                                                       |  |  | -->
<!-- | ...        | ...        | ...                      | ...                                                           |  |  | -->
<!-- | 2007-12-11 | 2007-12-17 | Dominican Republic (the) | Bonao city (Monsenor Nouel district, Monsenor Nouel province) |  |  | -->
<!-- | 2007-12-11 | 2007-12-17 | Dominican Republic (the) | Nagua district (Maria Trinidad Sanches province)              |  |  | -->
<!-- | 2007-12-11 | 2007-12-17 | Dominican Republic (the) | Arenoso                                                       |  |  | -->
<!-- | ...        | ...        | ...                      | ...                                                           |  |  | -->
<!-- +------------+------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--+--+ -->
```

Your kind help is appreciated. The following is part of the data.table:

```
   Start.date   End.date                  Country ISO
1: 2004-01-05 2004-01-05           American Samoa ASM
2: 2004-09-02 2004-09-03            Bahamas (the) BHS
3: 2004-08-25 2004-09-08            Bahamas (the) BHS
4: 2005-10-19 2005-10-25            Bahamas (the) BHS
5: 2007-10-28 2007-11-02 Dominican Republic (the) DOM
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     Location
1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             American Samoa
2:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Abacos, Andros, Berry Islands, Bimini, Eleuthera, Grand Bahama, New Providence islands (Administrative unit not available)
3: Acklins, Berry Islands, Biminis, Black Point, Cat Island, Central Abaco, Central Andros, Central Eleuthera, City of Freeport, Crooked Island, East Grand Bahama, Exuma, Grand Cay, Harbour Island, Hope Town, Inagua, Long Island, Mangrove Cay, Mayaguana, Moore's Island, New Providence, North Abaco, North Andros, North Eleuthera, Ragged Island, Rum Cay, San Salvador, South Abaco, South Andros, South Eleuthera, Spanish Wells, West Grand Bahama
4: Acklins, Berry Islands, Biminis, Black Point, Cat Island, Central Abaco, Central Andros, Central Eleuthera, City of Freeport, Crooked Island, East Grand Bahama, Exuma, Grand Cay, Harbour Island, Hope Town, Inagua, Long Island, Mangrove Cay, Mayaguana, Moore's Island, New Providence, North Abaco, North Andros, North Eleuthera, Ragged Island, Rum Cay, San Salvador, South Abaco, South Andros, South Eleuthera, Spanish Wells, West Grand Bahama
5:                                                                                                                           Santo Domingo, Distrito Nacional, San Cristobal, Peravia, Azua, Barahona, Pedernales, Independencia, Baoruco, San Juan, Santiago, Puerto Plata, Espaillat, Salcedo, Duarte, La Vega, Monte Plata, Monsenor Nouel, Hato Mayor, El Seibo, Dajabon, Monte Cristi, Santiago Rodriguez, La Altagracia, San Pedro de Macoris provinces
   Latitude Longitude Magnitude.value Magnitude.scale Disaster.type
1:       NA        NA             310             Kph         Storm
2:       NA        NA              NA             Kph         Storm
3:       NA        NA              NA             Kph         Storm
4:       NA        NA              NA             Kph         Storm
5:    18.53    -70.06              NA             Kph         Storm
   Disaster.subtype Associated.disaster          Associated.disaster2 Total.deaths
1: Tropical cyclone                  --                            --            0
2: Tropical cyclone                  --                            --            2
3: Tropical cyclone                  --                            --            1
4: Tropical cyclone                  --                            --            1
5: Tropical cyclone               Flood Slide (land, mud, snow, rock)          129
   Total.affected Total.damage...000.US.. Insured.losses...000.US..
1:          23060                  150000                         0
2:           8000                 1000000                    230000
3:              0                       0                         0
4:           1500                       0                         0
5:          79728                   77700                         0
       Disaster.name Disaster.No.
1:              Heta    2004-0004
2:           Frances    2004-0455
3:              Ivan    2004-0462
4: Hurricane "Wilma"    2005-0585
5:              Noel    2007-0523
```

Comment: can you put some part of the data instead so that we can play with it?

Comment: @Eyayaw I have edited it. Now it's a few lines from the real data. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I meant some part of your data frame, not a markdown table. Can you do `head(df, 10)` or `dput(head(df, 10))`?

Comment: Just added it. @Eyayaw

Comment: I am sorry, that is a lot of data to be  read in. Could you try `dput(head(df[c("Start.date", "End.date",        "Country", "Region") ]))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to specify the `sep` as a regex lookaround

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
disasters %>%
      separate_rows(C, sep = "(?<=Region.),\\s*|(?<=\\)),\\s*")
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  A        B        C                    
#  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>                
#1 Country1 Oct 2000 Region1              
#2 Country1 Oct 2000 Region2              
#3 Country1 Dec 2016 Region1              
#4 Country1 Dec 2016 Region2(City1, City2)
#5 Country1 Dec 2016 Region5
```

---

Using the updated dataset, one option is

```
lst1 <- strsplit(disasters2$Region, "\\(.*?\\)(*SKIP)(*F)|,\\s*", perl = TRUE)     
nm1 <- setdiff(names(disasters2), "Region")
out <- transform(disasters2[rep(seq_len(nrow(disasters2)), 
     lengths(lst1)),nm1], Region = unlist(lst1))    


row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#  Start.date   End.date    Country                                         Region
#1 2005-10-10 2005-10-16 Costa Rica Quepos (Aguirre district, Puntarenas province)
#2 2005-10-10 2005-10-16 Costa Rica                            Guanacaste province
#3 2016-11-23 2016-11-25 Costa Rica                                          Upala
#4 2016-11-23 2016-11-25 Costa Rica                                        Bagaces
```

#### data

```
disasters <- structure(list(A = c("Country1", "Country1"), B = c("Oct 2000", 
"Dec 2016"), C = c("Region1, Region2", "Region1, Region2(City1, City2), Region5"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

disasters2 <-   structure(list(Start.date = c("2005-10-10", "2016-11-23"), End.date = c("2005-10-16", 
"2016-11-25"), Country = c("Costa Rica", "Costa Rica"), 
Region = c("Quepos (Aguirre district, Puntarenas province), Guanacaste province", 
"Upala, Bagaces")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! However, I should be clear about "RegionA" or "City1" are the generic case, they actually have real different names in my data. How can I solve this problem then?

Comment: The complete response has been edited. I pressed the enter button by mistake. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I have just edited the data.

Answer (score 0):

This might serve your cause.

```
txt <- c("Region1, Region2",
 "Region1, Region2(City1, City2), Region5",
 "RegionA, RegionB (CityA, CityB, CityC)",
"RegionF, RegionG" )   

#split at `,` followed by a `space` but not by `City` then a `number` or a `capital letter`
strsplit(txt, "(,\\s(?!City[[:upper:]]|\\d))", perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "Region1" "Region2" 

[[2]]
[1] "Region1"       "Region2(City1" "City2)"        "Region5"      

[[3]]
[1] "RegionA"                       "RegionB (CityA, CityB, CityC)"

[[4]]
[1] "RegionF" "RegionG"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!